# Span position inside anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I have a `span`inside the `anchor`element. 
All I want is:
1) Have a width for the `anchor` text, so that it does not overlap on the `span` element.
2) The `span` element should be aligned to the first line of the anchor text
3) The `span` element to be right of the `anchor` text

```css
a {
  width: 147px;
  display: inline-block!important;
}
span.expand {
  background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/deadsimple/youtube.gif) no-repeat right center;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  padding-right: 14px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    Enrollment to communication skills 
    <span class="expand"></span>
</a>
```

I have no other choice but to use `span` inside `anchor`, even though it is not a recommended.

Comment: do you need to have a span inside an anchor? or are other implementations also possible?

Comment: Are you expecting something like this https://jsfiddle.net/nf6hrh2b/5/ ?

Comment: @Pugazh - Looks like what you have mentioned and what I have answered too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301720/span-position-inside-anchor-tag/30301840#30301840

Comment: @NKL I tried to eliminate the `span` tag. However the output is same.

Comment: @Pugazh - Agreed. Not sure why OP mentioned that "I have no other choice but to use span inside anchor".

Comment: @Pierezzz : I have no choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want to achieve, but based on what you have mentioned, here is the solution.

**[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nf6hrh2b/2/)**

**The CSS Change:**

```
a {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block!important;
}
span.expand {
  background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/deadsimple/youtube.gif) no-repeat right center;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  background-position: top right;
  padding: 11px;
  float: right;
}
```

**Edited CSS Change:**

If the width needs to exist without setting it to `auto`, below is the code.

**[WORKING DEMO WITHOUT AUTO WIDTH](https://jsfiddle.net/nf6hrh2b/10/)**

```
a {
  width: 135px;
  display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

}
span.expand {
  background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/deadsimple/youtube.gif) no-repeat right center;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  background-position: 0 0px;
  padding: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 1px;
  right: 17px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. But having `width:auto`, wont help. I have fixed width criteria.

Comment: But it you are using a fixed width, then the text will overflow. Are you fine with that? - @Archana

Comment: Do one thing. If you want a fixed width, then just increase the same to say 256px. It will also work. Working demo as below. https://jsfiddle.net/nf6hrh2b/7/ - @Archana

Comment: Exactly. the test will overflow. That is where I am stuck. My width will be 135px. That is the requirement. More than that width, the text will overflow to next line while having the icon intact.

Comment: Here you go @Archana with width 135px. https://jsfiddle.net/nf6hrh2b/8/ Does that work now?

Comment: I dont see line break. As I go on adding more words, it is working as if width is auto.

Comment: Thanks, but my requirement is to have icon aligned to the first line of the link. I have posted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a few ways. One way is by moving the `<span>` outside the anchor. Another way is by adding the background image to the anchor and remove the span.

Both ways are visible in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpoa06x8/

```
<a href="#">
    <!-- using a backgroundimage -->
    Enrollment to communication skills 
</a>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<a class="href" href="#">
    <!-- using an extra span -->
    Enrollment to communication skills 
</a>
<span class="extend"></span>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  width: 146px;
  display: inline-block!important;
  background-image: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/deadsimple/youtube.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 120px 0px;

}

/* Second example */
.href{
    background-image: none;
    float:left;
    display:block !important;        
}
.extend{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  background-image: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/deadsimple/youtube.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width:15px;    
  height:15px;
}
```

Comment: I want the span to work as link too. That is why I have made it part of anchor.

Comment: @Archana ok, then I recommend you to use my first example. Just add the image as an background-image to your anchor and remove the span.

Comment: OK. But in my code, I have something like navigation links. Few links has icons and few don't. And that is updated dynamically based on the page url. So span is used. I cannot use background for anchor, since it will append icon for all the links

Answer (score 0):

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nf6hrh2b/6/)

I added `:after` pseudo-element instead `.extend` with `position:absolute;`

```
a {
    width: 147px;
    display: inline-block!important;
    position:relative
}
a:after {
    background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/deadsimple/youtube.gif) no-repeat right center;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: OK. But in my code, I have something like navigation links. Few links has icons and few don't. And that is updated dynamically based on the page url. So span is used. I cannot use :after, since it will append icon for all the links

Comment: You can add class to all anchor with icons